# wordpress rendering invisible

Tags: wordpress

I have a page on a wordpress site located here: http://www.3cdesignsolutions.com/?page_id=331

It's not rendering anything visible but I know the code is there because I'm pasting it into the editor and I can see it in the admin area. Ideas?

```
<div id="album-6"><br></div><script type="mce-text/javascript"><!--
    /** SCRIPT TO ENSURE window.onload WORKS FOR ALL BROWSERS ****************/
    function init() {
      if (arguments.callee.done) return;
      arguments.callee.done = true;
      // do your thing
      loadAjaxPage("touch-ups","../../ajax.get-photo-touch-ups.php");
    }
    if (document.addEventListener) {
      document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init, false);
    }
    (function() {
      /*@cc_on
      if (document.body) {
        try {
          document.createElement('div').doScroll('left');
          return init();
        } catch(e) {}
      }
      /*@if (false) @*/
      if (/loaded|complete/.test(document.readyState)) return init();
      /*@end @*/
      if (!init.done) setTimeout(arguments.callee, 50);
    })();
    _prevOnload = window.onload;
    window.onload = function() {
      if (typeof _prevOnload === 'function') _prevOnload();
      init();
    };
    /** AJAX FOR RFQ FORM SUBMISSION *****************************************/
    var ajax = new sack();
    function whenLoading(element){
        var e = document.getElementById(element);
        e.innerHTML = "Sending Data...";
    }
    function whenLoaded(element){
        var e = document.getElementById(element);
        e.innerHTML = "Data Sent...";
    }
    function whenInteractive(element){
        var e = document.getElementById(element);
        e.innerHTML = "Getting data...";
    }
    function whenCompleted(){
        /* do nothing...*/
    }
    function loadAjaxPage(el,file){
        ajax.requestFile = file;
        ajax.element = el;
        var onLoading = whenLoading(ajax.element);
        var onLoaded = whenLoaded(ajax.element);
        var onInteractive = whenInteractive(ajax.element);
        ajax.onCompletion = whenCompleted;
        ajax.runAJAX();
    }
// --></script><br> <!-- LOAD RSS FEED INTO DIV -->
```

Comment: Javascript is being wrapped with `<p>` tags for any wordpress guru's who might recognize that as an obvious red flag.